# Adding Link button Event Dynamically

Tags: c#

I am Creating a Table Dynamically by passing a html code to a sting.

Now I want to add a link button and If i click on that then that row i want to delete.

please help me
thanks in Advance

Comment: How do you fill the table? do you have a sample code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you're missing some vital information here, such as if you're using Web Forms / Razor etc - each of which would be different responses. Please can you add further information and example use cases to you question

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the linkbutton first and bind event with the button... for example

```
       HtmlGenericControl td = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
       LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
       //lnk.ID = set your dynamic ID;
       lnk.Text = "Delete";
       lnk.Click += new EventHandler(Clicked);

       td.Controls.Add(lnk);
```

Now create the function for click on button

```
       protected void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          // do work on click...

       }
```